# on click of button attach to method with dynamic parameters in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

In a C# class I've method Method1, of type void, taking two parameters: int a and int b.
In Method2, I create dynamically some link buttons, which I wanna associate with Method1, however:

```
x[i].OnClickClient += new EventHandler(Method1(1,2));
```

where x[i] is the index i Link Button, renders an error: "Method name expected".
What is the right syntax for this? Does OnClickClient work for this?
I've seen examples that involve having a method like:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

but I don't want to create a separate method for each button because I might have 100 buttons, so the clicking should be associated dynamically with Method1, for any button in the group, and only the parameters will differ (they will be incremented dynamically as well).
Thanks.

Comment: use server click, cannot use client to call server method. _per se_

Comment: Kramb, I don't have OnServerClick in my suggestions/autocomplete list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax would be:

```
x[i].OnClickClient += new EventHandler(Button_Click);

protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button button = (Button)sender;  // Which button was clicked;

    // Now you can do stuff with the button that was clicked
}
```

Comment: How is the Click method linked to Method1(a,b)? Syntax is a bummer. Thanks!

Comment: @Halle You can call `Method1(a,b)` from inside the `Button_Click()` method. Where are you getting the values for `a` and `b`? I don't understand how they relate to the buttons.

Comment: the tricky part is a, which is the current button index (the button is in an array of buttons, so I would need to pass i from x[i] to ButtonClick, which in turn calls Method1 based on i).

Comment: Main problem now is that Button_Click is not at all invoked.

Comment: Apparently this is because the button click causes the page to load, which recreates the buttons and their properties (I have a generate buttons method inside load). Is there a way to attach an event to the button click without the page load being invoked? a is the index of the button, thus equal to i in x[i].Text, whereas b is a class constant. Presumably x[i].Text should be accessible through button.Text (I can't verify as the Button_Click is not triggered at the moment).

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a lambda expression :

```
x[i].OnClickClient += (sender, e) => Method(1,2);
```

Comment: Unf, I get: cannot convert lambda expression to type string because it's not a delegate type; operator += cannot be applied to operands of type string and lambda expression. Should sender and e be declared? Thanks!